# typeorm 'Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.'

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nestjs and typeorm(mysql).

I'm typing `orIgnore` to use 'Insert Ignore', but I get the same error as the title.

```js
Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.
```

Below is my code.

```js
await this.userSearchRepository
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into(User_SEARCH)
            .values({
              userId: user.id,
              etc1: user.name,
            })
            .orIgnore()
            .execute();
```

Below is the query displayed in the console when executed.

```sql
INSERT  IGNORE INTO `User_SEARCH `(`id`, `userId`, `etc1`,`etc2`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: [39,"aaaaaaa"]
```

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'table_name' AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

And when the above query is executed, normal values ​​are output.

The table structure is as follows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE User_SEARCH {
  id INT primary key auto increment,
  userId INT FK,
  etc1 varchar(255) not null,
  etc2 varchar(255) null
}
```

When I type the query in mysql workbench it works fine.

If I put `id:null`, it works, but is there a fundamental solution?

---

```js
@Entity()
export class User_SEARCH {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  userId: number;

  @IsString()
  @Column()
  etc1: string;

  @IsString()
  @Column({nullable:true})
  etc2: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userSearch, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn({
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
    name: 'userId',
  })
  user: User;
}
```

Comment: How is your entity class defined? Can you please post the `User_SEARCH` entity definition?

Comment: @RahulSharma I added it at the bottom!

Answer (score 2):

**[updateEntity](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/51b2a63d/src/query-builder/UpdateQueryBuilder.ts#L340)** function might be helpful to you in this case.

> **updateEntity**: Indicates if entity must be updated after insertion operations. This may produce extra query or use RETURNING / OUTPUT statement (depend on database). Enabled by default.

Set this as `false` to your query.

```
await this.userSearchRepository
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into(User_SEARCH)
            .values({
              userId: user.id,
              etc1: user.name,
            })
            .orIgnore()
            .updateEntity(false) // Include this one
            .execute();
```